# Full Screen overlay without back/home/menu button

Tags: android, user-interface

I have this function to show a fullscreen black overlay on my activity. To mimic screen off behaviour.

```
private void showBlackOverlay() {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    dialog.show();
}
```

But still back/home/menu buttons are visible. How can I hide them?
**I need it to work on older versions of android also.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
View decorView = dialog.getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, from Android 4.4 (API Level 19), you can do this. You can check the details here : https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

just tried this code on my nexus 7 (Android 4.4.2) and works fine

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            decorView
                    .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The DecorView is the view that actually holds the window’s background drawable. Calling getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable() from your Activity changes the background of the window by changing the DecorView‘s background drawable.